# Android room many-to-one relationship

Tags: kotlin, foreign-keys, android-room, many-to-one

I cannot find anything about this type of relation (everything is *about one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many*). And even those look a little bit too complicated for what I need.

I have a table with tasks and a table with images. Multiple tasks can have the same image in order to save space (the image is not deleted when the task is deleted). I have an entity for the task

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import androidx.room.*

@Entity(tableName = "tasks")
class Task(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long,

    val imageId: Long = 0,

    // this needs a foreign key to Image
    val image: Image
)
```

and another one for the image

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "images")
class Image (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long,

    val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
    val data: ByteArray? = null
)
```

How do I add a `foreignKey` for the `imageId` column so that it points to an `Image`? Can I directly obtain an `Image` object as a member of `Task` without having to create another class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use one-to-many relationship here. There is an [example](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many) from d.android.com. If you will do like that you will have a Task entity, an Image entity and data class TaskWithImage, just like in the example provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
data class TaskWithImage(
    @Embedded val task: Task,
    @Embedded(prefix = "img_") val image: Image
)

@Query("""
    SELECT * FROM tasks
    INNER JOIN images as img_ ON tasks.id = img_.id
""")
fun getTasksWithImage(): List<TaskWithImage>
```